# Rails 3.2: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Trying to create an instance of a model, I get the following error...

```
u = User.create
# or .where(...).first_or_create
# or .where(...).first_or_initialize
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Is anyone having the same problem with Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you overloaded your model's `initialize` method? In my case, I had overloaded it with:

```
def initialize(attributes=nil)
    ...
end
```

Which I had to fix to:

```
def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
    ...
end
```

In Rails 3.2, the commit 7c5ae0a88fc9406857ee362c827c57eb23fd5f95 (Added mass-assignment security :as and :without_protection support to AR.new) added more arguments to the above method and that's why my previous implementation was failing.

Comment: Wow, that is an amazing catch. The error message and stack trace gives absolutely no hint to the location of this one.